# iTextSharp PdfTextExtractor returns without whitespace between endline

Tags: itext

while using PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage, I extracted text into a text document, however all the whitespace after each endline was missing.  I tried to replicate this issue with a simple three line PDF file created from MS word and was unsuccessful, each endline was replaced by an extra space.

***Below is a PrtScn of the PDF file***

[image: PDF]

***Below is text displayed by notepad***

```
February 04, 2013Patient:  Ima . TestD.O.B.:   6/14/1970Chart #:   2004-00001SSN:  555-55-5555Dr. :Enclosed you will find the report for Ima . Test.
```

Words ending on the same line were not separated with the words beginning on the next line.  I assumed this would cause problems when I wanted to parsing the string.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-none --> doesn't seem to disable syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Below is the same text displayed by notepad++***

```
February 04, 2013
Patient:  Ima . Test
D.O.B.:   6/14/1970
Chart #:   2004-00001
SSN:  555-55-5555
Dr. :
Enclosed you will find the report for Ima . Test.
```

I didn't know that notepad doesn't recognize endline, so when I copied and pasted the same text into question box, each line was separated.  Hopefully this will save someone a little bit of time who ran into the same problem.

Comment: It is common knowledge that Notepad expects a carriage return and a newline character (or \r\n, which is the Windows-way of ending a line) whereas Notepad++ expects only a newline (\n, which is the *NIX-way of ending a line). You should accept your own answer. That way people can see that your own response answered your question.